# HDMI sound doesn't work on an Asus EEE

Tags: sound, ubuntu-netbook, hdmi

I installed Ubuntu-Netbook remix to Asus EEE series. And plugged device to a Sony television through HDMI interface. But I can't get any sound from television but sound is available from the headset jack of Asus EEE.

Can you help me about this issue ?

I perform some google search and seems that the issue is historical one.

Comment: The output of `lspci` and `aplay -l` please.

Answer (score 2):

You likely have HDMI output turned off in the audio configuration.

The `pavucontrol` package installs the Pulse Audio Volume Control Utility.  The configuration panel allows you to turn on output.  Your HDMI output should then show up in the output panel.

Comment: I will try and let you know from this post. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Open the sound configuration from the top panel and select the "HDMI" device as the output sound device.